# Combining asp net linkbutton onclick and onclientclick with javascript popup

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, boolean

I have this popup that I want to stick when editing an operator. The problem is that I `return true`so that I can get access to code-behind, but when doing this, my popup instantly closes, if I `return false`: the popup will stick but the code will never go to code-behind. What should I do? (Also, my linkbutton is inside a repeater)

JavaScript:

```
function PopupEdit($this) {
    if ($($this).attr("disabled") === "disabled") {
        return false;
    }
    var module = $($this).parent().find("#modalEdit");
    module.show();
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target === module) {
            module.hide();
        }
    };

    return true; //Right here is the problem.
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:LinkButton CommandName="selectBtn" ToolTip="TRNSLTEdit" ID="btnEdit" CssClass="editOperator" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' OnClientClick="return PopupEdit(this)">
<asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Edit-16x16.png" ID="EditVisitor" runat="server" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

C#:

```
    protected void rptList_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
         var tellusUserId = TellusUser.UserID;
         var operatorId = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);

               switch (e.CommandName)
               {
                case "selectBtn":
                var btnEdit = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnEdit");
                btnEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;"); //I tried this, but does not work.
                var operatorsDataSet = _administrationSystem.GetOperatorForEdit(tellusUserId, operatorId);

                if (operatorsDataSet != null)
                {
                    ViewState["OperatorsForEdit"] = operatorsDataSet;
                }
                break;
                }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your popup is getting close because of page is going to server so popup dialog is closed. you have to open your popup from code behing from your linkbutton's click event in your C# code you have to register your script like

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "PopupEdit", "PopupEdit("+lnkControl.ClientID+");", true);
```

This will work

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "ShowProduct", "PopupEdit();", true);` did not work. Also: where did you get "ShowProduct" from?

Comment: that was my code you have to pass your control CLient Id. I have change code